Axler's proof that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $f + g$ is also measurable
I'm puzzled by a step in a proof by Sheldon Axler contained in Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (p. 35). The claim to be proved is the following:

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $f, g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable. Then $f + g$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.

His proof begins as follows:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We will show that $$(f + g)^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \left(f^{-1}((r, \infty)) \cap g^{-1}((a - r, \infty))\right),$$ which implies that $(f + g)^{-1}((a, \infty)) \in \mathcal{S}.$

I have troubles understanding the implication step. Can someone hint at why it follows from the above equality?

A function is measurable if the preimage of a measurable set is measurable. What Axler says is that he will show that the preimage of $(a,\infty)$ under $f+g$ is measurable, by showing it is a countable intersection and union of measurable sets.

An approach here I would prefer, rather than an explicit argument, is that the function $(f\times g)(x, y) := (f(x), g(y))$ is still measurable as a function from $(X\times X, \mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{S})$ to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2})$, and so after composition with $x\mapsto (x, x)$, which is measurable, and composition with addition $(x, y)\mapsto x+y$ which is continuous so Borel measurable, the function $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ is measurable as composition of measurable functions.

Because $f$ and $g$ are measurable, the inverse images of open intervals under them are measurable. Furthermore, since countable unions and intersections of measurable sets are measurable, the set on the RHS is measurable.

By "measurable" you mean that they are elements of $\mathcal{S}$, right? I've only seen functions defined as measurable so far, not sets (sorry, I'm very new to measure theory). So the two inverse images are in $\mathcal{S}$ because $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be measurable, and the countable union of their intersection is also in $\mathcal{S}$ because of the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, correct? I think this is what Axler is saying.

Sorry I've just realised that the definition of a measurable set is precisely a set that is an element of a $\sigma$-algebra, so nevermind, ignore that part of my comment. Thanks a lot for answering.

Yes, that’s correct.
